# Is there a way to compile java code in real time

Tags: java, compilation

I'm thinking about making a game where the user gives commands on what they want the game to do and one problem I am having is I'm not sure how to compile their script and run it

Comment: Maybe this is what you’re looking for: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/CompileString.htm

Comment: You know of the JSR233 scripting api?

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to write a _complete program_?  Or just to have a menu of commands they can execute?

Comment: @LouisWasserman either or is fine

Comment: Having a menu of commands, rather than executing code entered by the user, is _astronomically_ easier.  Just switch on a string executed by the user, and execute an appropriate function depending on what they entered.